# do practices or make an internship?

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering which form is correct.

I want to say that I wanted to gain experience, let's say in a school, as a teacher, and I spent some period of time there with mentor who supervised my activities.

What should I say?

I was "doing my practices" as a teacher at a public school.

or

I was "making my internship" as a teacher at a public school.

or maybe

I was "doing my practice" as a teacher at a public school.

What are your suggestions?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In Britain, student teachers have to spend time in schools as part of their course, and it is called 'school practice' (or was when I worked in the education sector).

Comment: Also called [teaching practice](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/teaching-practice) by my relatives who undertook it. "I was doing my teaching practice at a public school".

Comment: Thank you for your support!

Comment: To me "doing my internship" sounds the most natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *specific* case of learning to teach at a school as a student, and as part of an education qualification, that might be called "teaching practice".

> I did my teaching practice at a public school.

(No plural. "Practice" is uncountable in this sense. And remember that "public school" has the exact opposite meaning in British English and American English)

You would not normally be able to do teaching practice except as part of an education qualification.

Otherwise, you could speak of an "internship":

> (I was an intern / I interned / I had an internship ) at Dupont.

Another useful word might be "apprentice" (A person learning a trade while also studying).

Comment: So, to say "I was doing/having my internship as a baker" or "I was on an internship as a baker" would still be correct?

Comment: Perhaps, but perhaps you were working as an apprentice baker.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!